# iOS: How to initiate a call to an address book contact with special characters (#/*) in the number?

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook, abaddressbook

I am currently working on an iOS application that uses live audio streaming, and our users have asked for a feature to automatically block incoming calls when they are streaming. I know that there is no API to do this, so the way we solved it is to have a button on the UI that automatically calls a certain number (specific to the telecom provider) that turns blocking of incoming calls on or off. It does this simply by opening a tel: URL.

This all works fine, and while it may not be very user friendly because it forces users to exit the application, I do belive it's the most elegant solution with the tools provided by the iOS API.

There is one caveat though, some telecom providers do not have a single short number that people can call to turn this feature on or off. They use instead long codes that have special characters in them, such as # and *. Unfortunately iOS refuses to open tel: URLs with those characters, presumably for security reasons. However I was wondering if it is possible for users to put those numbers into contacts and then have iOS call those contacts directly?

I know how to retrieve phone numbers from the address book directly, but that's no use because I will still have the problem of the URLs not getting accepted. So is there instead a way to, say, have tel: URL with a contact ID or something similar?

Thanks for reading and/or replying. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't dial # or * from an app.  It's Apple's scheme to protect us from nasty people.

To quote from Apple's documentation:

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing
>   the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application supports
>   most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme.
>   Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone
>   application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.

...and converting to ASCII characters and other tricks doesn't work either (I tried).